# Can I configure git to run a command (on push)?

Tags: git, build, automation, automated-tests, build-automation

I've been using hosted Git and enjoying it a lot.

I want to automatically run unit tests when I push to my git repo, and I want these tests to be run on multiple different machines (which are on different platforms that I intend to support).

[It seems like](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) it will be pretty simple to set up git repos as servers that I can push code to, but I know of no simple way to fire off e.g. `make && make test` when something gets pushed to the repo.

The alternative I came up with is to push to a repository (I can keep my hosted repo this way) and then use a completely separate method to trigger on my test servers a `git pull && make && make test`. This is perhaps more elegant but I feel like it's not an ideal solution.

I'd also like for my servers to report back program output or at least a return value so I can tell if the tests failed or not. But that is out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at a "post update hook".

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html